# Importing from temp table SQL

Tags: sql, insert, sql-server-2012, addition

I have a problem when trying to add rows from a tempTable to a table. The problem is that it adds the rows from TempDealer table even if they're already in the Dealership table (Notice that I'm specifying in the WHERE Statement WHERE td.supplier_ref NOT IN (SELECT supplier_ref FROM @dealerStatus). Every time I run the stored procedure it adds again all rows from the TempDealer to the Dealership table when it should only add them once. Any ideas? thanks in advance.

```
        INSERT INTO @dealerStatus (dealerId, supplier_ref, [add], [timestamp])
            SELECT NULL, td.supplier_ref, 1, GETDATE()
                FROM TempDealer td 
                WHERE td.supplier_ref NOT IN (SELECT supplier_ref FROM @dealerStatus) 

            INSERT INTO Dealership( 
                    dealership_name, 
                    telephone, 
                    fax, 
                    sales_email, 
                    support_email, 
                    service_mask, 
                    address1, 
                    address2, 
                    town, 
                    county, 
                    postcode, 
                    website, 
                    date_modified, 
                    supplier_ref, 
                    dealer_type, 
                    county_id, 
                    town_id, 
                    area_id, 
                    district_id,
                    longitude,
                    latitude
                    ) 

                SELECT DISTINCT
                        [updateSource].leasing_broker_name, 
                        [updateSource].telephone, 
                        [updateSource].fax_number, 
                        [updateSource].email, 
                        [updateSource].support_email, 
                        [updateSource].service_mask, 
                        [updateSource].address1, 
                        [updateSource].address2, 
                        [updateSource].town, 
                        [updateSource].county, 
                        [updateSource].post_code, 
                        [updateSource].web_address, 
                        GETDATE(), 
                        [updateSource].supplier_ref, 
                        1, 
                        [updateSource].county_id, 
                        [updateSource].town_id, 
                        [updateSource].region, 
                        [updateSource].district, 
                        [updateSource].longitude,
                        [updateSource].latitude
                    FROM 
                        @dealerStatus dealerUpdateStatus INNER JOIN 
                        TempDealer [updateSource] ON dealerUpdateStatus.supplier_ref = updateSource.supplier_ref
                    WHERE 
                        dealerUpdateStatus.[add] = 1
```

Comment: Right now you're saying "Insert into (at)dealerStatus every row from TempDealer that doesn't have a supplier ref matching one that's already in (at)dealerStatus". The problem there is that when it's checking this, (at)dealerStatus is empty. You need to change your WHERE clause to NOT IN (SELECT supplier_ref FROM Dealership) instead, I think.

Comment: I did, it doesn't insert anything whit WHERE td.supplier_ref NOT IN (SELECT supplier_ref FROM Dealership). Seriously this is driving me crazy, it cannot be that complicated

Comment: It's hard to figure out what's going wrong with it since obviously I'm not the one looking at the tables, but let me have a closer look.

Comment: I fixed it! thanks for the orientation John Clifford you were right, I had to select the supplier_ref from Dealership table as the way I had it before the INSERT in @dealerStatus was never happening  ;)

Answer (score 1):

I sorted it out this way:

```
        INSERT INTO @dealerStatus (dealerId, supplier_ref, [add], [timestamp])
            SELECT NULL, td.supplier_ref, 1, GETDATE()
                FROM TempDealer td 
                WHERE td.supplier_ref NOT IN (SELECT supplier_ref FROM Dealership WHERE dealership.supplier_ref IS NOT NULL and dealership.dealer_type = 1)
```

Comment: Glad I was able to sort-of help you kind of perhaps maybe? XD